# UML Linux - vmlinux.o Error 1 - final close failed: Input/output error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, user-mode-linux

I'm trying to install UML linux. Kernel is 2.6.28.

I link to Linux files so that I have a read-only copy that I can revert back to.

I then run the commands:

```
make defconfig ARCH=um  # works
make ARCH=um            # errors out at the very end:
final close failed: Input/output error
make: *** [vmlinux.o] Error 1
```

Because of this error, my binary vmlinux never gets created so I can't run my own UML Linux. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](http://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/48759/) fix the problem?

Otherwise, more information is needed.  Host's architecture, distribution, and versions of tools (GCC, binutils, Make, shell, ...).